# Regex to match words in sentence after a pattern

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to capture the group `fish egg chicken beef` in the sentence `How much is fish egg chicken beef ?`. I tried with

```
how much is ((?>\w+))* \\?
```

But its only returning `fish` as the second group. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: this cannot actually match. there is nothing to match the spaces between the words. are you sure this is the exact pattern you are using?

Comment: Absolutely. This is just what I need. Also there can be more words.

Comment: Your comment doesn't change anything about the fact that your current pattern [cannot possibly match](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=4d265755-f302-48ba-88d7-4bc3b46656a4). So I wonder how you obtained the capture `fish` with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the regex should be:

```
How much is (.*)\?
```

Or if you want to match all the words but one word in each capture:

```
How much is (?:(\w+)\s*)+\?

Regex regexWords = new Regex(@"How much is (?:(\w+)\s*)+\?");

foreach(Capture word in regexWords.Match(input).Groups[1].Captures)
{
    // word.Value contains one word.
}
```

Good luck with your quest.

Comment: Does the jobs it seems.